# Null pointer exception when querying database from a Quartz job

Tags: java, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

My scheduler is triggering but I am not able to connect to the database. When I tried to query the database using a test case it worked so I tried to implement it using Quartz, but it's giving a `NullPointerException`.

```
public class JobScheduler extends QuartzJobBean {
    @Autowired
    ISourceService sourcedao;
@Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setClientKey(300);
        Source sourceobj = sourcedao.getSourceByClient(client);
        String sourcetype = sourceobj.getSourceType();
        System.out.println(sourcetype);
    }
}
```

my application context.xml

```xml
<bean id="jobScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.dca.scheduling.JobScheduler" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cronTriggerjobScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobScheduler" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/15 0 * * * ?" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jobScheduler" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTriggerjobScheduler" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobClass"
        class="com.dca.scheduling.JobScheduler">
    </bean>
```

I checked many examples but didn't get any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JobScheduler needs to be a Spring bean, too.  You don't show how you annotate it.  I would make it a Component and see if you fare better.

Comment: is it necessary to give @component annotation

Answer (score 0):

in the application context i have added a map

```
<bean id="jobScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.dca.scheduling.JobScheduler" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                 <entry key ="DATA_MANAGER_MAP_KEY" value-ref="sourceDao"/>**i have added the bean id here**
                <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and in the **Jobscheduler class**

```
sourceDao= (SourceDaoImpl)jobContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("DATA_MANAGER_MAP_KEY");
```